# Валидация в XHTML

Tags: xml

Тип документа: XHTML 1.0 Transitional
Код:

```
<table width="100%">
   <tr width="100%">
      <td width="5%">...</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Валидатор пишет: Нет атрибута "Ширина"
Вопрос: он что слепой или это я чего-то понять не могу?

Comment: Блин, отредактируйте, пожалуйста, чтобы код отобразился.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

тег `<tr>` не поддерживает атрибут `width`
Если вы про `there is no attribute "width"` - то это означает, не то, что нет атрибута а то, что он не нужен

Answer (score 2):

> Нет атрибута "Ширина"

А как насчёт того, чтобы прочитать пояснение к этой фразе?

> You have used the attribute named above in your document, but the document type you are using does not support that attribute for this element.

И вообще

> there is no attribute "width"

надо переводить как

> Не существует атрибута ширина.

Что означает, что использовать такой атрибут нельзя.

Если бы говорилось о том, что надо указать атрибут, формулировка была бы c not specified:

> required attribute "type" not specified

Comment: С английским, к сожалению, не очень хорошо. А переводчик перевел: Не атрибута "ширина". Так что мне тогда делать, если нужно указать ширину? Сделать через CSS?

Comment: Да, указать через css.

Comment: @IT-Expert: Выучить английский, очевидно же. Онлайн-переводчики — источник хорошего настроения, но никак не замена знанию языка. В IT без английского никуда.

Comment: @VladD, несколько странно советовать выучить английский людям на RU.SO - ресурсе, который был специально создан для тех, кто не может пользоваться английским SO. Поверьте, тут львиная доля вопросов будет связана с плохим знанием языка. И это нормально. Будьте снисходительны, помогайте по мере сил.

Comment: @СергейСнегирёв: Я примерно так и делаю. Но тем не менее, английский — lingua franca современного программирования, его нужно знать. Хотя бы для того, чтобы понимать сообщения об ошибках.

Answer (score 0):

http://soledar10.com.ua/layout/user/
валидацию проходит

Стили отдельно прописывайте

http://jsfiddle.net/19von9g8/

```css
.table{
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse:collapse;
  width: 100%;
}
.table tr{
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.table tr td{
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.table tr .td1{
    width: 5%;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">           
                <tr>
                    <td class="td1">1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                </tr>       
            
        </table>
```